# every time i replace fragment with another number of fragment in my fragmentManager increases

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing an Android application with a navigation View, I noticed that every time I replace a fragment with another the total number of fragments in my Fragment Manager increase until my application crushes with this error :

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1
```

I noticed that the number increases with a message in my Log in onNavigationItemSelected function :

```
Log.d("fragmentNumber:", fragmentManager.getFragments().size() + "");
```

this is my function I called when replacing a fragment with another :

```
public void showFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a `replace()` and an `addToBackStack()`.  So let's say you have fragment instance 1.  You run the code and replace it with fragment instance 2. The `addToBackStack()` call means that the fragment manager must hold on to fragment instance 1, since you might press the Back button and it would have to undo the replace and re-display fragment 1.  This will happen with the third, fourth, fifth fragments and on and on, until you run out of memory.  And notice that I said "instance".  It doesn't matter if the fragments are all the same class or not; when you say `new MyFragment()` you're creating a new instance.  And each instance is going to take up more and more memory -- until you run out.

Rather than replacing each time, you may want to navigate back to a fragment if it's already on the back stack.  Let's say you replaced a `DataListFragment` with a `DataDetailsFragment`.  If the user wants to navigate to the `DataListFragment` using your navigation button (rather than the Back button), you can call `fragmentManager.popBackStack()` to simulate pressing the Back button and redisplaying the `DataListFragment`.

If you can't keep track of the navigation that simply, you can mark a back stack entry using `addToBackStack(String name)` then later use `FragmentManager.popBackStack (String name, int flags)` to return to that fragment state.

Managing the fragment state and back stack is tricky.  If I could show you the mass of code I just wrote to handle this, your eyeballs might pop (but the code is proprietary, so I can't).